# Unable to start Oculus in Unity Editor

Tags: unity-game-engine, editor, oculus

Hi everyone) I can't see the oculu's rotations in unity editor when press play button. No errors(((

Unity - 2019.4.37f1 
Oculus XR Plugin - 1.12.0 (try 1.11.2)
XR Interaction Toolkit - 2.0.1
XR Plugin Management - 4.2.1
Facebook account - development settings done
Oculus - unknown sources is on, development mode is on
connect Oculus to PC via link usb 2.0
Unity Project Settings: XR Plugin Management (android tab) Oculus is on
Install apk on Oculus via Unity (build button) - works fine

What could be the cause of this problem? Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled windows, reset the helmet to factory settings, bought a new usb 3.0 cable, installed unity 2021. The cable connection is established. The cable passes the test.

I still can't see the oculu's rotations and other actions in unity editor when press play button((

maybe i need to install some kind of application on the helmet?

Answer (score 0):

Hi This might too late for you, but might help for others having same problem
Please install OpenXR plugin on unity and from the oculus app goto settings -> general -> click on SetOculusAsActive

from the unity editor configure the OpenXR for windows platform
[image]